# Can you run an F# script file (.fsx) using .net core?

Tags: .net-core, f#, mono

Is it possible to run .fsx files using .net core? (Equivalent to `fsharpi` on Mono.)

Comment: What did you tried for this?

Comment: I tried `fsi` but it's not available yet on .net core - I hear the team will be adding this feature at some stage. Therefore, currently I'm using `fsharpi` from mono.

Comment: @Martimatix I know this is an old question but now that .NETCore3 includes this out of the box, would be good to switch the accepted answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It works out of the box in .NETCore v3.0 or newer:

```
$ cat hello.fsx
#!/usr/bin/env fsharpi
printfn "hello world"
$ dotnet fsi hello.fsx
hello world
$ dotnet --version
3.0.100
```

PS: Side-note: if you want to compile your scripts without having to run them, check [this tool](https://github.com/nblockchain/fsx).

Answer (score 6):

I went looking for this answer and the best I could find matches your comment @Martimatix from March 28 however I did find issue 2407 in the visualfsharp repo which tracks the [support for fsi on .NET Core 2.0](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/2407).

Update (April 2009):
It looks like there is now a preview version now for .NET Core available.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-preview-3/

Answer (score 4):

They are working on it. [This is the main issue,](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/2407) the same one posted by *jpierson*.

You can try right now with something like this:

```
dotnet /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.403/FSharp/fsi.exe test.fsx
```

It kinda / sorta works, but there are parts missing, especially full support for `#r` and interactive line editing (readline).

Comment: No luck here
```pwsh
PS C:\Users\info\Projects\Insights> dotnet fsi .\experiment.fsx
No executable found matching command "dotnet-fsi"
PS C:\Users\info\Projects\Insights> dotnet fsi.exe .\experiment.fsx
No executable found matching command "dotnet-fsi.exe"
PS C:\Users\info\Projects\Insights> dotnet $(which fsi) .\experiment.fsx
No executable found matching command "dotnet-/c/Program Files/dotnet/sdk/2.1.403/FSharp/fsi"
```