# GithubActions CI Windows VMs don't have fsi.exe anymore? or it changed location

Tags: .net, f#, continuous-integration, github-actions, f#-interactive

Before you tell me that the way to run `.fsx` scripts in .NETCore/.NET5(or higher) is `dotnet fsi`, FYI: [I know that already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58121483/544947). I just can't upgrade yet, so I'm still running my .fsx scripts with the good-old .NET 4.x Framework.

To do this, and to run them under GithubActions CI, I had this handy `fsi.bat` file:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET ENTERPRISE="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\fsi.exe"
SET COMMUNITY="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\fsi.exe"
SET BUILDTOOLS="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\fsi.exe"

IF EXIST %ENTERPRISE% (
    SET RUNNER=%ENTERPRISE%
) ELSE (
    IF EXIST %COMMUNITY% (
        SET RUNNER=%COMMUNITY%
    ) ELSE (
        IF EXIST %BUILDTOOLS% (
            SET RUNNER=%BUILDTOOLS%
        ) ELSE (
            ECHO fsi.exe not found, is F# installed?
            EXIT /b 1
        )
    )
)

%RUNNER% %*
```

This was working fine... until yesterday.

Somehow GitHub (or should I say Microsoft...) decided to upgrade their production VMs for GitHub Actions and now all my builds are failing.

So I have three questions:

1. What is the location now? I don't see that VS2020 has been released yet?
2. Any better way to find fsi.exe moving forward that cannot break after upgrades?
3. How to choose a more stable GitHubActions VM that doesn't bring breaking changes from time to time? Don't just tell me to yell at Nat Friedman on twitter :)

Comment: It's a dotnet tool now. Try `dotnet fsi`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the location changed recently for me also:

- VS2019 version 16.9.3: `...\Microsoft\FSharp\fsi.exe`
- VS2019 version 16.10.0: `...\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools\fsi.exe`

So they've moved it into a `Tools` directory for some reason.

What I do personally is start the "Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt" and execute `fsi` from there, so the exact location doesn't matter. Maybe you can script something similar by invoking the same command file? It's in `...\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat`.

Comment: and to find the VsDevCmd I also have to probe for 3 possible locations?